# Temporary saving data somewhere which can be saved after user registration

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring MVC with hibernate project. Below is the database schema for the project. This project is basically about making 'notes' which are divided in various sections and saving them. Also the user can have various 'canvases', thus the column 'canvas number'.

The problem I am facing is, there is public homepage, which is built using HTML, java-script and is used before login. Any user can add,edit,delete on public homepage, but cannot save it in database or the canvas. He/She is redirected to login/registration page. But we want to save all the notes in some sort of buffer so it can be saved directly in database once user logsin/registers completely. Any idea what I can use for the buffer mechanism??

[image: Database schema]

Comment: Mmmm...The data can vary, and I want save it properly, with notes,id's of specific tables. I am looking into it though, anything more?

Comment: And why wouldn't that be possible with the session? You just store it temporarily and after login, continue to the original URI/controller which just proceeds as normal.

Comment: Ok. I think I will have to check session then.